# UITableVIewCell Error Xcode 7 / Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, xcode7

I ran into the following error in this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? UITableViewCell
```

ERROR: Downcast from 'UITableViewCell?' to 'UITableViewCell' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Change `UITableViewCell?` to `UITableViewCell!`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In `Swift2.0` method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is declare as:

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

You shouldn't cast `UITableViewCell` to `UITableViewCell?`. See code below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

As of Xcode 7, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will always return a non optional `UITableViewCell`.

You don't even need to specify the type, it can be written succinctly as:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
```

or if you have a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? SomeOtherCell else { fatalError("unexpected cell dequeued from tableView") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CMessageCell=self.MessageTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomMessageCell") as! CustomMessageCell
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use identifier you should use those methods :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WHAT-EVER-YOU-WANT-TO-CALL-IT", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
}
    return cell
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as UITableViewCell!
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please always provide explanations to your answers. Code only answers are rarely helpful. First of all everybody reading your answer has to figure out what you want to say (here it is just a one character difference), and then we all have to guess why you propose this as a solution. Always ask yourself, why is your answer better than the others already existing answers? If you cannot explain that, don't post.